# Update sql server database tables using mail-merge feature of MS Word

Tags: sql-server, mailmerge, docx-mailmerge

Can we update the SQL Server Database tables using mail merge feature of MS Word in c#. If yes How can we do this ?

Comment: You've not made any improvements to your original question here. Though you shouldn't be reposting questions; there is an edit feature you can use, which if you sufficiently improve your question, will mean it will go through the reopen queue successfully.

Comment: Try searching "using word as offline data entry"